# Block data duplication when moving from Geth to Eth (or vice versa)

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, cpp-ethereum

I've so far been using Geth (the Go client) as my client of choice. I'm now interested in using the Mix IDE, a requirement of which is that I use Eth (the C++ client) instead.

I've already synced the block data for the Geth client. Is it necessary that I also sync the same block data a second time, for the Eth client? If both clients use the same data structure to store the data, and they store it in the same place (`~/.ethereum`) then presumably they can just share (he says). Is this going to be the case?

(Follow-on question: Does Eth have an equivalent to Geth's `--fast` flag?)

Comment: Maybe ask the follow-on question separately; I don't recall, otherwise I'd answer it here in this comment.  (By the way, nothing wrong with duplicates, just helps route to the same answer.)

Comment: Agree with the duplication - thanks very much. Didn't spot it when I searched beforehand. I'll create another question for the follow-up.